# How to install MySql-python-1.2.3 on Mac OS 10.8

Tags: python, mysql, macos

I've downloaded http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/

and also downloaded Xcode and command line tools.

When I used this command "sudo python setup.py build"

I see this:

```
running build
running build_py
copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-        aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -  Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -pipe -  Dversion_info=(1,2,4,'beta',4) -D__version__=1.2.4b4 -  I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/mysql -  I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o    build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/_mysql.o -mmacosx-version-min=10.4 -arch i386 -arch ppc -D_P1003_1B_VISIBLE -DSIGNAL_WITH_VIO_CLOSE -DSIGNALS_DONT_BREAK_READ -DIGNORE_SIGHUP_SIGQUIT -DDONT_DECLARE_CXA_PURE_VIRTUAL
clang: warning: not using the clang compiler for the 'powerpc' architecture
_mysql.c:44:10: fatal error: 'my_config.h' file not found
#include "my_config.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

How can I do now???

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Would be great if someone could help.

Answer (score 2):

MAMP's version of MySQL doesn't come with the dev headers. You have to either download and install an official MySQL release, or integrate the headers into MAMP according to: http://dreamconception.com/tech/how-to-install-mysqldb-mysql-python-on-mamp/

Comment: Have a look at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218229/my-config-h-file-not-found-when-intall-mysql-python-on-osx-10-8]

Answer (score 2):

Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51351548/1723626) before trying this solution. Anyway, had the same problem, this worked for me -

```
brew install mysql-connector-c
brew install mysql
brew link --overwrite mysql
pip install MySQL-python
```