# error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1 - MySQLdb installation on MAC

Tags: python, mysql-python

I am new to Mac and i am trying to install MySQLdb for Python on MAC but after following the steps mentioned on http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_database_access.htm, i received an error after running

```
$ python setup.py build
```

Error:

```
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
_mysql.c:44:10: fatal error: 'my_config.h' file not found
#include "my_config.h"
     ^
1 error generated.
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

Note: My "mysql_config" path is /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql_config
What should i do?

Comment: have you checked out this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15505840/how-to-install-mysql-python-1-2-3-on-mac-os-10-8

Comment: Yes and i already have XAMPP and XAMPP have MySQL - Now i want to resolve this issue using the existing MySQL in XAMPP

Answer (score 9):

The problem is unused arguments passed to compiler. Try this before running your build code:

```
export CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
export CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
```

Comment: +1 for me on `Mac OS X` `10.9 Mavericks` it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: i had to add those line to `.bash_profile` and restart the bash to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting this on the terminal before executing:

```
export CC='/usr/bin/gcc'
export CFLAGS='-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk -I/opt/X11/include -arch i386 -arch x86_64'
export LDFLAGS='-arch i386 -arch x86_64'
export ARCHFLAGS='-arch i386 -arch x86_64'
```

found it here: https://jamesfriend.com.au/installing-pygame-python-mac-os-108-mountain-lion

Comment: For OSX El Capitan: Use above with below CFLAGS:

export CFLAGS='-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include -arch i386 -arch x86_64'

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today, and I had to downgrade the MySQL 8 to 5.7 to install the Python module.

This procedure worked for me:

```
brew remove mysql mysql-client mysql-connector-c
brew install mysql@5.7
brew link --force mysql@5.7
pip install mysql-python
```

I read a post and adjusted the procedure to link things in the /usr/local/bin instead of adding a new route to the PATH variable.
Reference: [MacOS: "pip install MySQL-python" returning an error: "_mysql.c:44:10: fatal error: 'my_config.h' file not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63990900/macos-pip-install-mysql-python-returning-an-error-mysql-c4410-fatal-err)