# Mac pip install mysql-python unsuccessful

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pip

I installed MySQL and Workbench from website. I have a django project whose requirements.txt:

```
Django==1.11.12
djangorestframework==3.8.2
django-cors-headers==2.2.0
drfdocs==0.0.11
mysql-python==1.2.5
django-rest-auth==0.9.3
django-allauth==0.35.0
nltk==3.2.5
django-extensions==2.0.7
pyparsing==2.2.0
pydot==1.2.4
```

When I run

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I got an error `mysql_config not found`. To solve this I ran

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

It now throws

```
    _mysql.c:44:10: fatal error: 'my_config.h' file not found
    #include "my_config.h"
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command ""/Users/nitish/gitProjects/Vision Backlog/vb_env/bin/python" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/ql/_w2_rlvs2351pdcnzhn04sf40000gn/T/pip-install-M4ue9E/mysql-python/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/ql/_w2_rlvs2351pdcnzhn04sf40000gn/T/pip-record-7OCzf1/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers "/Users/nitish/gitProjects/Vision Backlog/vb_env/include/site/python2.7/mysql-python"" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/ql/_w2_rlvs2351pdcnzhn04sf40000gn/T/pip-install-M4ue9E/mysql-python/
```

Why is this happening?

UPDATE: following bellow solution threw:

```
Collecting MySQL-python
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a5/e9/51b544da85a36a68debe7a7091f068d802fc515a3a202652828c73453cad/MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/ql/_w2_rlvs2351pdcnzhn04sf40000gn/T/pip-install-X6b4rU/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "setup_posix.py", line 53, in get_config
        libraries = [ dequote(i[2:]) for i in libs if i.startswith(compiler_flag("l")) ]
      File "setup_posix.py", line 8, in dequote
        if s[0] in "\"'" and s[0] == s[-1]:
    IndexError: string index out of range
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please, try:

```
CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments pip install -r requirements.txt
```

If it does not work:
First install **mysql-connector-c**

```
brew install mysql-connector-c 
pip install MySQL-python
```

If you are using Windows:

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/

You can also check what happend when you try install it with `pip3.`

*UPDATE:*
If you have Linux: 
Please open the `/usr/local/bin/mysql_config`.

And then:

```
#Create options
Libs = "-L $ pkglibdir "
Libs = " $ libs   -l"
```

replace with:

```
#Create options
Libs = "- L $ pkglibdir"
Libs = "$ libs -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto"
```

Save it and reinstall `mysql-python`.

```
pip uninstall mysql-python
pip install mysql-python
```

For Mac:

```
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib pip install mysql-python
```

should be helpful.

Comment: I have python 2.7 and pip version 10.0.1

Comment: I am on mac and running these two commands still threw me error (see updated question)

Comment: Glad to help you!

Comment: I also had to follow this afterwards: https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/issues/169#issuecomment-299778504

Comment: Thank you so much! This is the only comment I have seen to work
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib pip install mysql-python

Answer (score 39):

Installing of an older version of the MySQL worked for me:

```
brew remove mysql
brew install mysql@5.7
brew link --force mysql@5.7
pip install mysql-python
```

See:

- [issue on the MySQLdb1 Github](https://github.com/farcepest/MySQLdb1/issues/119)
- and [this sof answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51343325/command-cc-failed-with-exit-status-1-on-osx-high-sierra/51351548#51351548)

Comment: Thanks a mil! Spent a few minutes struggling with this until I found your answer :)

Comment: This was it! It was the MySQL version 5.7 that did the trick. (I had to install an older MySQL-python version 1.2.5)

Comment: I used my_config.h from mariadb and put it in /usr/include. Then pip2 install mysql-python works perfect.

Answer (score 4):

```
brew install mysql@5.7
export PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.7/5.7.29/bin:$PATH"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.7/5.7.29/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1d/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.7/5.7.29/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1d/include"
/Users/tivanli/source/bk_project/pizza/venv/bin/pip install MySQL-python==1.2.5
```

Comment: Works great on Catalina 10.15.7 for an old python project I had to stand up. Just had to update the paths to reflect the mysql  (5.7.32) and openssl (1.1.1h) that get installed at the present time.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was:

```
brew install mysql-connector-c 
pip install MySQL-python
pip install mysql-connector
```

Answer (score 0):

Those who are facing this issue on **Ubuntu** even after installing all the required packages. They can follow this

- Copy the Source for **my_config.h** from official url-

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/mysql-server/8.0.11/my__config_8h_source.html

Then create a file in **/usr/include/my_config.h** and paste it

```
sudo nano /usr/include/my_config.h
```

you can paste the content using ctrl + shift + v, depending on your distribution.

Now install the package, your version or no version.

```
 pip install mysqlclient==1.3.7
```

You can get the source of the file from official link depending upon the SQL version.

**Original Link** - http://www.kombitz.com/2020/04/29/my_config-h-no-such-file-or-directory-on-centos-8/

Answer (score -3):

Just uninstall your Mysql, and install MySql 5.7
and is fixed!!!!

If you are not successful from any of the above solutions, it means that your MySql version is not matching the requirements. i was thinking that it is because of Python or PyCharm, and i used virtualenv and conda but no luck, so when i compared my dependencies to one of my friend's computer, it was MySql version. downgraded to 5.7 and its working fine.