# mysql-python installation error

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, mysql-python

I am setting up django rest project with mysql. I installed all my dependencies including mysql-python:

```
Django==1.11.12
djangorestframework==3.8.2
django-cors-headers==2.2.0
drfdocs==0.0.11
mysql-python==1.2.5
django-rest-auth==0.9.3
django-allauth==0.35.0
nltk==3.2.5
django-extensions==2.0.7
pyparsing==2.2.0
pydot==1.2.4
```

I needed few tweaks as discussed here [Mac pip install mysql-python unsuccessful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50864438/mac-pip-install-mysql-python-unsuccessful)

Now when I try to run `python manage.py migrate` I get following error:

```
(VB_env) shannon:VB_Backend_SCG nitishpatkar$ python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 52, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 124, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 325, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 214, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 211, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 115, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 30, in <module>
    'Did you install mysqlclient or MySQL-python?' % e
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: dlopen(/Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so, 2): Symbol not found: _mysql_affected_rows
  Referenced from: /Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so.
Did you install mysqlclient or MySQL-python?
```

Why is it happening? I am on mac and I have installed MySQL as well.

UPDATE:

```
(VB_env) shannon:VB_Backend_SCG nitishpatkar$     pip install mysqlclient
Requirement already satisfied: mysqlclient in /Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (1.3.12)
(VB_env) shannon:VB_Backend_SCG nitishpatkar$ python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 52, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 124, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 325, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 214, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 211, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 115, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 30, in <module>
    'Did you install mysqlclient or MySQL-python?' % e
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: dlopen(/Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so, 2): Symbol not found: _mysql_affected_rows
  Referenced from: /Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so.
Did you install mysqlclient or MySQL-python?
(VB_env) shannon:VB_Backend_SCG nitishpatkar$
```

UPDATE 2:

```
(VB_env) shannon:VB_Backend_SCG nitishpatkar$ pip list
Package             Version  
------------------- ---------
certifi             2018.4.16
chardet             3.0.4    
Django              1.11.12  
django-allauth      0.35.0   
django-cors-headers 2.2.0    
django-extensions   2.0.7    
django-rest-auth    0.9.3    
djangorestframework 3.8.2    
drfdocs             0.0.11   
idna                2.7      
MySQL-python        1.2.5    
mysqlclient         1.3.12   
nltk                3.2.5    
oauthlib            2.1.0    
pip                 10.0.1   
pydot               1.2.4    
pyparsing           2.2.0    
python-openid       2.2.5    
pytz                2018.4   
requests            2.19.1   
requests-oauthlib   1.0.0    
setuptools          39.2.0   
six                 1.11.0   
typing              3.6.4    
urllib3             1.23     
wheel               0.31.1   
(VB_env) shannon:VB_Backend_SCG nitishpatkar$
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to install mysqlclient in order to use mysql with django.

Run this command

```
    pip install mysqlclient
```

Comment: error shows it is not installed. try install once again and check.  in /Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so.
Did you install mysqlclient or MySQL-python?

Comment: I tried to freshly install mysqlclient and updated my stacktrace.

Comment: I also deleted my virtualenv and did a complete reinstall with pip install -r requirements.txt but the same error persists.

Comment: try  pip uninstall mysql-python
pip install mysql-python

Comment: pip list .. run this command and check if package is installed.. can you paste the installed packages

Answer (score 0):

Before Installing do 'Upgrade' and 'Update' and later try to install 'mysqlclient'

Answer (score 0):

can you try install the below two packages and try

Python3

```
-> sudo apt-get install python-dev python3-dev
-> sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

Python2.7

```
-> sudo apt-get install python-dev python2.7-dev
-> sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

Comment: I am using python 2.7, wouldn't that be a problem?

Comment: Sure,by the way I am on mac